# Model geometry point with ORMLite

Tags: postgresql, geometry, point, ormlite

I am using PostgreSQL as the database for my application. I also use the ORMLite as the mapping.

In a table of the database I use point as the datatype to store position (x,y) of targets.

So my question is: how to map type point in PostgreSQL in ORMLite?

Comment: Is this for ORMLite the Java ORM?  Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Are you referring to the Point type from the PostGIS extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "point")
public class Point {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, index=true)
     public Long id;

     @DatabaseField()
     public Integer x;

     @DatabaseField()
     public Integer y;


}
```

But yes, please make your question more clear

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but i have also been looking for a solution and did not find one.

here a proposal for a patch of ormlite

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/issues/68